# Resizing a volume in terraform without enable_online_resize?

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to `terraform apply` and recreate the storage volume rather than setting `enable_online_resize` or running a `terraform destroy` first?

```
openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3.repo: Modifying... [id=87049fb6-1520-41e3-bcde-44f837dd5d1f]
╷
│ Error: Error extending openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3 87049fb6-1520-41e3-bcde-44f837dd5d1f,
│                                       volume is attached to the instance and
│                                       resizing online is disabled,
│                                       see enable_online_resize option
│ 
│   with openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3.repo,
│   on main.tf line 60, in resource "openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3" "repo":
│   60: resource "openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3" "repo" {
```

I realize I'll lose the data on the volume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`--replace`](https://www.terraform.io/cli/state/taint) like this,

```
terraform apply --replace=openstack_blockstorage_volume_v3.repo
```